# rsync: connection unexpectedly closed - Migration from AWS to Digital Ocean

Tags: ssh, rsync, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to migrate my Django site from AWS to DigitalOcean. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/migrate-your-current-vps-linode-rackspace-aws-ec2-to-digitalocean)

My problem is that I can't `rsync`my files. Just as info, I'm able to connect via ssh to my Digital Ocean's server

From mysite/settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # which equal at mysite-aws-folder dir
```

commands

```
localhost:mysite-aws macuser$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x@  7 macuser  staff   238 Jul 25 16:24 .
drwxr-xr-x@  9 macuser  staff   306 Jul 26 13:37 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 macuser  staff  8196 Aug  9 14:22 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@ 20 macuser  staff   680 Jul 25 16:04 bin
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 macuser  staff   646 Jul 25 16:04 mysite-aws-folder
drwxr-xr-x@  3 macuser  staff   102 Jul 25 16:04 include
drwxr-xr-x@  3 macuser  staff   102 Jul 25 16:04 lib
localhost:mysite-aws macuser$ rsync -avP mysite-aws-folder root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html/
building file list ... 
2001 files to consider
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
localhost:mysite-aws macuser$
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem trying to backup to rsync.net. They told me that the last part, after the colon ":", should be a local pathname to add to an existing directory.

> rsync -avP mysite-aws-folder root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html/

should be

> rsync -avP mysite-aws-folder root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:var/www/html/